# Transfering funds from India to the US

Tags: united-states, india, loans, non-resident, transfer

I am a US Citizen doing business in India as well as US.

1. Can I transfer funds from India to USA which I have borrowed in India.
2. Is there a limit on one time transfer of funds from India to the US?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I transfer funds from India to USA which I have borrowed in India.

Funds borrowed in India may not be transferred outside of India as per [Foreign Exchange Management Act.](https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/BS_FemaNotifications.aspx?Id=158)

> **Loans in rupees to non-residents against security of shares or
>   immovable property in India:-**
>   Subject to the directions issued by
>   the Reserve Bank from time to time in this regard, an authorised
>   dealer in India may grant loan to a non-resident Indian,
>
> e) the loan amount shall not be remitted outside India;